# Javascript array using forloop , odd and even number goes out of the range i had set

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am suppose generate numbers between 1-10,  50 times, using for loops to display the output as shown:

Original Array :1 5 3 4 5 6 8 7 5 7 4 5 6 8 7 5 7 2 3 5 4 5 6 8 7 5 7 8 5 4 5 8 7 4 1 5 6 3 2 5 4 7 1 0 2 3 6 5 4 7

Even Numbers :0 2 4 6 8 10

Odd Numbers :1 3 5 7 9

**however this is my out put:**

```
**Original Array:** 
3 1 4 5 5 8 6 8 6 6 6 6 3 4 4 2 3 4 2 1 5 10 3 3 3 6 1 8 2 7 9 6 8 8 5 1 4 8 7 8 8 4 1 10 10 3 10 8 10 9 4

**Odd Array:** 
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39 41 43 45 47 49

**Even Array:**
0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 42 44 46 48 50
```

**my code**

```
var intArray = [], evenArray = [], oddArray = [], i;

for (i = 0; i <= 50; i++) 

{
    intArray[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
}

for (i=0;i<intArray.length;i++) 


{
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        evenArray.push(i)
    } else {
        oddArray.push(i)
    }
}

console.log("Original Array: \n" + intArray.join(" "))

console.log("Odd Array: \n" + oddArray.join(" "))

console.log("Even Array: \n" + evenArray.join(" "))
```

Comment: `i` is your for loop index, not the value in your array.. you want `if (intArray[i] % 2 === 0)`

Comment: JavaScript also offers an Array.filter function - for even: intArray.filter(x => x % 2 === 0)  and for odd: intArray.filter(x => !(x % 2 === 0))

Comment: For 50 times, remove the "=": `for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is checking the value of i, not the value of intArray[i], and pushing the value of i, not the value of intArray[i] into the even/odd arrays.
fixed your code, now it should work as expected.

```js
var intArray = [],
  evenArray = [],
  oddArray = [],
  i;

for (i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
  intArray[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
}

for (i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
  if (intArray[i] % 2 == 0) {
    evenArray.push(intArray[i]);
  } else {
    oddArray.push(intArray[i]);
  }
}

console.log('Original Array: \n' + intArray.join(' '));

console.log('Odd Array: \n' + oddArray.join(' '));

console.log('Even Array: \n' + evenArray.join(' '));
```

Good Luck!

Comment: @user13812528 please explain what you mean by "3 output"